# Magento 2: Issues when deploying static content on EFS

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

When running the static content deploy with jobs option, we get this error:

```
In Queue.php line 366:

  Error while waiting for package deployed: 42; Status: 0  


setup:static-content:deploy [-f|--force] [-s|--strategy [STRATEGY]] [-a|--area [AREA]] [--exclude-area [EXCLUDE-AREA]] [-t|--theme [THEME]] [--exclude-theme [EXCLUDE-THEME]] [-l|--language [LANGUAGE]] [--exclude-language [EXCLUDE-LANGUAGE]] [-j|--jobs [JOBS]] [--symlink-locale] [--content-version CONTENT-VERSION] [--refresh-content-version-only] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [--] [<languages>...]
```

Static content deploy command:
`magento setup:static-content:deploy --jobs 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue open on Magento 2 repository and I even added a comment there: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21852

This issue might be caused by this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Process/Queue.php#L391
And the function for the timeout: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Process/Queue.php#L372
All points to const DEFAULT_MAX_EXEC_TIME = 400;
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Process/Queue.php#L32

So it looks like if the static code deploy runs for over 400 seconds, it will fail. But Magento has fixed their ECE tool to add an option to increase the timeout: https://github.com/magento/ece-tools/pull/418.
But for now this is not fixed on the Magento Open Source or Commerce edition.

So what can you do? Well, for now what we are going to do is to store the theme information for a store somewhere and when a code is deployed we get the theme and deploy only the theme assigned to a store. So for example if MageBR/mytheme is assigned to my store, I will run:

`magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme MageBR/mytheme`

It will speed things up and not fail as we can see below:

```
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2456/2456           ============================ 100% %  1 min               
frontend/MageBR/base/en_US                 2765/2765           ============================ 100% %  2 mins              
frontend/MageBR/mytheme/en_US           2765/2765           ============================ 100% %  2 mins

Execution time: 483.77401208878
```

I have the full article explaining here: https://blog.magebr.com/issues-when-deploying-static-content-on-efs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that if this error happens on Magento Cloud, the best solution is to add an environment variable to the `.magento.env.yaml` file to increase the `SCD_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` like the below (it defaults to `400`):

```
stage:
  deploy:
    SCD_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: 800
```